# EntityFramework 4.1, context.Entities.Add sometimes set FK to NULL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this weird problem that has burned way more hours than it should.

My main question is this:
**What may cause EF 4.1 Code First to set a foreign key to *NULL* when an entity is added?**

The problem is this: I have a list of users on file, and these users must be inserted to my database if they're not already there.

I have something like this:

```
foreach (var u in usersFromFile) {
    var userProfile = context.Users
        .FirstOrDefault(user=>
            user.EmployeeId == u.EmployeeId && user.CompanyId == 1);
    if (userProfile == null) {
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.EmployeeId = u.EmployeeId;
        newUser.CompanyId = 1;
        context.Users.Add(newUser); //This will sometimes set CompanyId = NULL
    }
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Some users won't be added to the Users table correctly.
They get CompanyId == NULL, and as such they do not belong to the company.

I also tried injecting SQL directly like so:

```
var query = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] 
              ([CompanyId],[EmployeeId]) VALUES (3,@emplid)";

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter("emplid", u.EmployeeId)});
```

- I have tried to access the Users list on the Company object. That does not work.
- I have tried to use context.Users.Create() instead of new User(). Does not change anything.
- I have tried to inject SQL, still the same problem. That exact SQL works, if ran from the Studio Manager.
- I have tried to context.SaveChanges() after each add, nothing changed.

I know for a fact that the state of the entity about to be added is correct, also in the cases where CompanyId is set to NULL.
Could there be something with my underlying database?

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
 foreach (var u in usersFromFile) {
    if (context.Users.Any(
          user=>
            user.EmployeeId == u.EmployeeId && user.CompanyId == 1)
       ) 
    {
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.EmployeeId = u.EmployeeId;
        newUser.CompanyId = 1;
        context.Users.Add(newUser); //This will sometimes set CompanyId = NULL
    }
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

The Any() function checks wether a user based on the given query exists.

Also, don't forget to add the context.savechanges to make sure every added record gets put in the database.

Lastly, you checked if user.CompanyId = 1, should be == 1

Comment: Thank you for pointing out some flaws in my example code. I could use Any for this simple case, but I eventually will need to make changes to the entity if it exists. I updated my initial entry to reflect the flaws you identified. Sadly, the error still exists in my code. CompanyId is still set to NULL sometimes.

Comment: Instead of adding the entity directly to the context and saying it has the Id 1, you could try the approach to fetch the company from your entity context and add the users to the company instead. Try: var comp = context.Companys.Where(c => c.Id == 1); comp.Add(newUser); context.savechanges();

Comment: Unfortunantly.. "I have tried to access the Users list on the Company object. That does not work." By access, I mean both for retrieval and for adding.

Comment: So there is no property Company.User? Then you have a different problem, you should map a virtual. If you are using the code first approach, add public IEnumerable<User> User {get; set;} to the Company entity and public virtual Company {get; set;} to the User entity. If using DB first, make sure the USER table has a foreign key pointing to company and refresh your scheme

Comment: There _is_ a property that is virtual IEnumerable<User> Users, but it does not change anything if I add my users through it.

Comment: And is there a property virtual Company Company as well?

Comment: On the context there is, the user has a CompanyId.

Comment: And to be clear, this is a website that has been running for two years so I presume it's not something basic.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up transforming the list of users to a series of SQL statemens, and running them through *context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql)*.

It's dirty but it works.

If anyone has any good ideas as to why the FK CompanyId on the user entity is sometimes set to NULL I'd we very happy if you share your ideas.